# How to do solr Multi Language search with single tokenizer

Tags: solr, multilingual

I wanted to develop the multi language search with single tokenizer for                 all language. Is it possible to develop in single core with multi language support in solr with single tokenizer for all language.

Comment: Which languages are we talking about? The ICUTokenizer can be configured for most languages that need special behaviour (where regular UTF breakpoints doesn't cut it by itself). That being said - the tokenizer is not usually the problem with having multiple languages in a single field, but normalization, sorting and proper stemming etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need of having separate tokenizer for each language.

I have a field type which is been used for German, French, Polish, English languages. Data/contents of different languages are stored in the same core and been supported.

I think that will work for you as well.

Are you looking for any other languages that the one mentioned?

Comment: I want to search all  language with same tokenizer.Is it possible in solr ??

Comment: Can you please  give me some idea how to do it ??